# How to "compile" a playground using CLI that is a part of a project/workspace?

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, command-line-interface, xcodebuild

I have a demo project setup like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/k0g47y8jtkrlg7h/PwP.zip?dl=0
[image: Project Setup]

`Start page` and `page two` are using code that is defined in `PWPCore framework`. I'm looking for a way to compile this playground as a step of CI. That way if some one changes code in the framework they have to update the playground that is using it.

Comment: You cannot "compile" a playground into an app / CLI target.

Comment: Here someone says it's possible ;) https://youtu.be/DrdxSNG-_DE?t=31m24s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One could use this tool in CI:

https://github.com/bow-swift/nef